# SQL Server 2008 R2 count of rows takes more time when returning values

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure which uses a view. The stored procedure accepts various parameters.

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(v.CampaignID) as RecordCount
FROM 
    VW_Results_ValueRank_2010_12_22_NEW V                        
INNER JOIN 
    ResultTopic ON V.ResultID = ResultTopic.ResultId    
INNER JOIN 
    CampaignTopic on ResultTopic.topicid = CampaignTopic.topicid         
WHERE 
    v.CampaignID = 37                        
    AND v.CreateDate BETWEEN 'May  3 2011  8:25PM' AND 'May  3 2012  8:25PM'                        
    AND v.SourceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-3,'May  3 2011  8:25PM') AND 'May  3 2012  8:25PM' 
    AND (LEFT(Title, 80) LIKE '%google%' OR Domain LIKE '%google%' OR LEFT([Text], 300) LIKE '%google%')
```

It returns 2016 records but takes 40-50 sec, can I decrease this time to 5-10 sec. Please help.

Comment: To speed things up, make sure you have indices on the `CampaignID`, the `CreateDate` and `SourceDate` columns. However, with the last WHERE clause - using `LIKE '%google%'` and `LEFT(...)` , you're pretty much making sure SQL Server cannot use any indices... can you try making sure you have indices in place, and try to run the query *without* the last part of the `WHERE` clause? Is it faster now?

Comment: If i remove where then it will get wrong data.

Comment: Thanks marc_s , so there is no way to make it fast with where.

Comment: Not with a `WHERE (LEFT(Title, 80) LIKE '%google%' ` - this prevents any indices from being used, so you have to do a full table scan, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for missed index by looking at execution plan and create them.

If all indexex are there and no index can be create on table then you can create index view for CreateDate , SourceDate and other columns in where clause.

[refer this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)